# Is it possible to create a websocket server with Oracle?

Tags: oracle, websocket, oracle-apex

I came accross the following article that explains how to make connections from Oracle PL/SQL to Websocket server : https://www.opencodez.com/oracle/oracle-pl-sql-programming-socket-connection.htm

In the example the Websocket server is written in Java.

I would like to know please if it's possible to create such Server with Oracle PL/SQL or Apex ? Which means a server that accepts websocket connections entirely inside Oracle environment.

I know that Oracle Apex allows to create RESTful API server. Was wondering if there is something that can be done for Websockets.

Thanks,
Cheers,

Comment: I made an example with nodejs but I think is similar, check my video https://youtu.be/0Uau-CUE8pA

Comment: And this one too https://youtu.be/t2o7DSVRZzo